# Python - Regular expression to find a phone number on a text

Tags: regex

I'm getting some trouble to find a regular expression to find a phone number in this format that allways start with the number "9" in the middle of a text:

```
90 00 00 000
```

I can find a number with this regular expression:

```
phones= re.findall(r'(\d{2})\D+(\d{2})\D+(\d{2})\D+(\d{3})', "55 66 66 778 xcvxcvxv 94 44 44 456")
print phones
> [('55', '66', '66', '778'), ('94', '44', '44', '456')]
```

But I need to find only the number started witn "9". How can I do this?

Best Regards,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just change the first `\d{2}` to `9\d`, however I'd recommend also changing it to match whitespace rather than non-numeric characters in between digits.

```
(9\d)\s+(\d{2})\s+(\d{2})\s+(\d{3})
```